# Some letters on my Turkish-layout keyboard don't work on Fedora

Tags: fedora, keyboard

I installed Fedora 25 as dual boot next to Windows 7. I have Turkish layout keyboard. And OS is in Turkish also. All the other buttons work and write normally, but buttons " i, ı, alt gr" dont function at all. These buttons work normally on Windows 7.

output of **setxkbmap -print**

> xkb_keymap {  xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
>     xkb_types     { include "complete"  };  xkb_compat    { include
>   "complete"    };  xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)" };
>     xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" }; };

and when I run `xev` as normal user and type characters, everything works normally.

`evtest` did not work in root user.

And I noticed that , when I type on terminal everything is ok.

Comment: Did you set up the same keyboard layout as in windows?

Comment: Please edit question with output of the following: 1) `setxkbmap -print`. 2) run `evtest` as root, select keyboard, press buttons that don't work 3) the same with `xev`, as normal user (make sure you have focus and can see output for other keys).

Comment: @dirkt I edited.

Comment: What do you have under "Input Sources" in "Region & Language" in the settings panel? (Sorry, I don't know what that is in Turkish....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run **setxkbmap tr** and It got fixed.

Comment: This will not persist after a reboot.

Comment: I created a $HOME/.profile file and added this "setxkbmap tr" command  inside it.